# Element next to other element Zend Form

Tags: css, zend-framework, zend-form

I have two elements in my form:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('valor_causa');
$element->setLabel('Valor da Causa: R$')
            ->setAttrib('class', 'moneyField')
            ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Float(array('locale' => 'pt_BR')));
$this->addElement($element);
$element = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('data_valor_causa');
$element->setLabel('Data do valor da causa:')
            ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Date(array('format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy')))
            ->setJQueryParam('dateFormat', 'dd/mm/yy')
            ->setAttrib('onkeypress', 'mascara(this,Data)')
            ->setAttrib('maxlength', '10');
$this->addElement($element);
```

It generates the following html code:

```
<dt id="valor_causa-label"><label class="optional" for="valor_causa">Valor da  Causa:R$</label></dt>
<dd id="valor_causa-element"><input type="text" class="moneyField" value="" id="valor_causa" name="valor_causa"></dd>
<dt id="data_valor_causa-label"><label class="optional" for="data_valor_causa">Data do valor da causa:</label></dt>
<dd><input type="text" maxlength="10" onkeypress="mascara(this,Data)" value="" id="data_valor_causa" name="data_valor_causa" class="hasDatepicker"></dd>
```

[image]
What could I do to let one element next to the other? like the picture above. I have tried removing all decorators but datapicker doesnt let me remove all. I tried some CSS but no sucess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `float` works for me:

```
dt {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

dd {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;  
}
```